# Hexdump utility in x86 NASM assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

It's a simple hexdump that prints to stdout. I wanted to handle correctly input coming from the user typing at the terminal, this made the logic a little more complicated than just exiting after reading less than requested. It doesn't use the stack or memory variables, except for the tables and buffers, so I employed every register freely.

I'm learning, so I would like for every possible improvement to be pointed out.

```
; Description     : Prints stdin to stdout as hex and displays ASCII next to it.
;                   It handles correctly the cases in which a sys_read returns
;                   less than was requested but an EOF was not received, this
;                   allows the user to dump arbitrary text from stdin to a file 
;                   in the following way: ./hexdump >> dump.txt
;
; Build using these commands:
;   nasm -f elf hexdump.asm
;   ld -o hexdump hexdump.o -m elf_i386 -s
;
; Usage:
;   ./hexdump << input_file

section .data
STDIN: equ 0
STDOUT: equ 1
STDERR: equ 2
EXIT_SUCCESS: equ 0
SYS_READ: equ 3
SYS_WRITE: equ 4
SYS_EXIT: equ 1
NEW_LINE: equ 0ah
AsciiTable: db '................................ !"',"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;"
            db '<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
            db '{|}~...........................................................'
            db '...............................................................'
            db '.......'
align 4
Template: db '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '
DivPos:   db '| '
AsciiPart: db '................',NEW_LINE
TEMPLATELENGTH: equ $-Template
align 2
HexTable: db '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2'
          db '02122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f40'
          db '4142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606'
          db '162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f8081'
          db '82838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a'
          db '2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabacadaeafb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9babbbcbdbebfc0c1c2'
          db 'c3c4c5c6c7c8c9cacbcccdcecfd0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9dadbdcdddedfe0e1e2e'
          db '3e4e5e6e7e8e9eaebecedeeeff0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff'

section .bss
BUFFERSIZE: equ 160
Buffer: resb BUFFERSIZE

section .text

global _start ; make it visible

_start:
        xor esi,esi                       ; position in buffer
        xor ebp,ebp                       ; buffer size
        mov edi,Read                      ; address to jmp
        mov esp,BUFFERSIZE                ; how much to read
  Fill: mov eax,SYS_READ
        xor ebx,ebx                       ; STDIN
        lea ecx,[Buffer+ebp]              ; destination
        mov edx,esp                       ; size
        int 80h                           ; call
        cmp eax,0                         ; check return value
        jg Ok                             ; read something
        jl Err                            ; < 0 -> error
        jmp Last                          ; 0 = EOF

  Ok:   add ebp,eax                       ; update size
  Read: lea esp,[esi+16]                  ; where we'll be if we print
        sub esp,ebp                       ; how much we have to read to reach 16
        jg  Fill                          ; esp > ebp
        jnz NotZ                          ; we only reset when esp = ebp
        mov edi,_start                    ; reset

  NotZ: mov ecx,15                        ; offset, not counter
        xor eax,eax                       ; clear bits 8-31
        xor edx,edx                       ; zero-out the upper half

  .l0:  mov al,[Buffer+esi+ecx]           ; read byte from buffer
        mov bx,[HexTable+eax*2]           ; get corresponding symbols
        mov [Template+ecx*2+ecx],bx       ; write to template
        mov dl,[AsciiTable+eax]           ; get ASCII symbol
        mov [AsciiPart+ecx],dl            ; write to template
        sub ecx,1                         ; next iteration
        jns .l0                           ; ecx is an offset not a counter

        ; Print the Template to stdout
  Out:  mov eax,SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx,STDOUT
        mov ecx,Template
        mov edx,TEMPLATELENGTH
        int 80h
        cmp eax,TEMPLATELENGTH
        jne Err

        add esi,16                        ; move index
        jmp edi                           ; go to Read or _start

  Last: sub ebp,esi                       ; make it a count
        jz Exit                           ; if 0, we are done
        sub ebp,1                         ; make it an offset

        mov ecx,15                        ; 16*4=64 (0 ... 15)
  .l0:  mov dword [Template+ecx*4],'    ' ; fill buffer with spaces
        sub ecx,1                         ; next iteration
        jns .l0                           ; ecx is an offset
        mov byte [DivPos],'|'             ; it was replaced by a space
        mov word [Template+64],'  '       ; finish writing spaces

        xor ebx,ebx                       ; clear
  .l1:  mov bl,[Buffer+esi+ebp]           ; get byte
        mov cx,[HexTable+ebx*2]           ; get corresponding hex code
        mov [Template+ebp*2+ebp],cx       ; place hex code
        mov bl,[AsciiTable+ebx]           ; get ascii symbol
        mov [AsciiPart+ebp],bl            ; place it
        sub ebp,1                         ; dec doesn't affect CF
        jns .l1

        mov edi,End                       ; return address
        jmp Out                           ; print last line

  Err:  mov ebx,-1                        ; EXIT_FAILURE
        jmp Exit

        ; Exit the program
  End:  xor ebx,ebx                       ; EXIT_SUCCESS
  Exit: mov eax,SYS_EXIT
        int 80h
```

Comment: `echo "abc" > i1` `./hexdump < ./i1` -> `03 31 13 05                                     | abc.`. Is it just me and the web online emulator I used, or the code has bugs? Anyway, that `AsciiTable` and `HexTable` is sort of mesmerizing for me, I did plenty of LUTs in my own code before, but very rarely cases like "x == lut[x]" or "simple_transformation(x) == lut[x]" survived.

Comment: @Ped7g you are absolutely correct about the bug. After the last `.l1:`, on the line `mov cx,[HexTable+ebx]             ; get corresponding hex code`, `ebx` should be `ebx*2` since each code is 2 bytes. I edited the code to fix it. I'm using the tables because they made the code easier to write and I believe they are faster, I'll benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refrain from using `esp` as general purpose register. This is limiting you in using `call`/`ret` subroutines, and you risk memory corruption caused by interrupt happening in your program context.

I would also refrain of such heavy LUT tables usage, as the program will be more likely limited by the I/O operations speed, so that tiny amount of calculation will quite likely hide in the buffered I/O waits.

Here is my version, avoiding those things mentioned above:

```
; hexdump.asm
; Description     : Prints stdin to stdout as hex and displays ASCII next to it.
;                   It handles correctly the cases in which a sys_read returns
;                   less than was requested but an EOF was not received, this
;                   allows the user to dump arbitrary text from stdin to a file 
;                   in the following way: ./hexdump >> dump.txt
;
; Build using these commands:
;   nasm -f elf hexdump.asm
;   ld -o hexdump hexdump.o -m elf_i386 -s
;
; Usage:
;   ./hexdump < input_file

STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_EXIT equ 1
NEW_LINE equ 0ah
BUFFERSIZE equ 16

section .data
HexLUT  db  '0123456789ABCDEF'

section .bss
ReadBuffer: resb BUFFERSIZE
DataBuffer: resb BUFFERSIZE

DIVIDER_OFFSET EQU 3*BUFFERSIZE
ASCII_OFFSET EQU DIVIDER_OFFSET+2
PRINT_BUFFER_SIZE EQU ASCII_OFFSET + BUFFERSIZE + 1
; = BUFFERSIZE * "%02x ", 2 chars for divider "| ", BUFFERSIZE * char + 1 for NEWLINE

PrintBuffer: resb PRINT_BUFFER_SIZE

section .text

global _start ; make it visible

_start:
        lea     esi,[DataBuffer]
        lea     edi,[DataBuffer+BUFFERSIZE]
Read:
        xor     ebx,ebx                 ; STDIN
        lea     ecx,[ReadBuffer]        ; buffer to read into
        mov     edx,BUFFERSIZE          ; BUFFERSIZE bytes at most
        mov     eax,SYS_READ
        int     80h
        cmp     eax,ebx                 ; check return value with 0
        jle     Finish                  ; < 0 -> error, 0 = no more bytes

CopyReadData:
        ; ecx = source of read data, eax = count
        ; esi = current DataBuffer, edi = end of DataBuffer
        cmp     esi,edi
        ja      .DataBufferIsNotFull
        ; display DataBuffer, when full
        call    DisplayDataBuffer
        lea     esi,[DataBuffer]        ; from the beginning of DataBuffer
.DataBufferIsNotFull:
        ; copy eax bytes from @ecx to @esi (clobbers bl)
        mov     bl,[ecx]
        mov     [esi],bl
        inc     ecx
        inc     esi
        dec     eax
        jnz     CopyReadData
        jmp     Read                    ; read more data

DisplayDataBuffer:
    ; esi = end of DataBuffer data
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx
        lea     ebx,[PrintBuffer]
    ; print BUFFERSIZE values as hexa "nn " string followed by space
    ; or three "   " spaces in case of no more data in buffer
        lea     ecx,[DataBuffer]
        mov     edx,BUFFERSIZE
PreparePrintBufferHex:
        cmp     ecx,esi
        jz      .noMoreData
        mov     al,[ecx]
        inc     ecx
        call    Format_AL_AsHexWithSpaceTo_EBX
        jmp     .finishLoop
.noMoreData:
        mov     [ebx],DWORD '    '
        add     ebx,3
.finishLoop:
        dec     edx
        jnz     PreparePrintBufferHex
    ; print divider between hexa and ASCII parts
        mov     [ebx],WORD '| '
        add     ebx,2
    ; print ASCII data (or spaces, when no more data)
        lea     ecx,[DataBuffer]
        mov     edx,BUFFERSIZE
PreparePrintBufferAscii:
        cmp     ecx,esi
        mov     al,' '
        jz      .validAscii     ; no more data
        mov     al,[ecx]
        inc     ecx
        cmp     al,0x7F         ; values 00-1F and 7F-FF are shown as '.'
        jae     .invalidAscii
        cmp     al,' '
        jae     .validAscii
.invalidAscii:
        mov     al,'.'
.validAscii:
        mov     [ebx],al
        inc     ebx
        dec     edx
        jnz     PreparePrintBufferAscii
    ; Add new line character at the end of line
        mov     [ebx],BYTE NEW_LINE
    ; Output PrintBuffer to screen
        mov     eax,SYS_WRITE
        mov     ebx,STDOUT
        lea     ecx,[PrintBuffer]
        mov     edx,PRINT_BUFFER_SIZE
        int     80h
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebx
        pop     eax
        ret

Format_AL_AsHexWithSpaceTo_EBX:
        push    eax
        shr     eax,4
        call    .EAX_nibble
        pop     eax
        call    .EAX_nibble
        mov     [ebx],BYTE ' '
        inc     ebx
        ret

.EAX_nibble:
        and     eax,0x0F
        mov     al,[HexLUT+eax]
        mov     [ebx],al
        inc     ebx
        ret

Finish:
        call    DisplayDataBuffer       ; display any incomplete line of data
        mov     ebx,eax                 ; error code from SYS_READ is exit code
        mov     eax,SYS_EXIT
        int     80h
```

Comment: Please explain: "you risk memory corruption caused by interrupt happening in your program context."

Comment: @ultra well, I'm not sure about linux, if such interrupt may happen triggered by OS or HW, but generally interrupt stores returning address on it's stack. If it would run in the same context as app code, it means it will push at least far address under current `esp`, probably lot more. I think under linux most of the interrupts happen in different [OS] context (so the switch is expensive, but fortunately for you they have their own `ss:esp`), although some graphics drivers have partial functionality (regarding 3D gfx) copied into user space to make the calls faster (omitting context switch).

Comment: @ultra but I have no idea about any details, never read anything about how linux kernel sets up interrupts, just generally on other CPUs where the context is shared between interrupts and app you can manipulate `sp` register only when interrupts are disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Some random thoughts:

- Unused defines: STDIN, EXIT_SUCCESS
- I'd restructure the code above `Ok:` to do `jz Last; jl Err` and just let jg fall thru (unless Last is further away than it looks).
- I don't believe it's safe to use esp as a general purpose register like this.
- Why do you `xor edx,edx` above .l0?
- I find your ebp/esp/edi logic confusing.  I've got an alternative, but I'm not on linux, so I can't actually run this (and I HATE posting code I haven't run), but how about something like:

.

```
; Description     : Prints stdin to stdout as hex and displays ASCII next to it.
;                   It handles correctly the cases in which a sys_read returns
;                   less than was requested but an EOF was not received, this
;                   allows the user to dump arbitrary text from stdin to a file 
;                   in the following way: ./hexdump >> dump.txt
;
; Build using these commands:
;   nasm -f elf hexdump.asm
;   ld -o hexdump hexdump.o -m elf_i386 -s
;
; Usage:
;   ./hexdump << input_file

section .data
STDIN: equ 0
STDOUT: equ 1
STDERR: equ 2
EXIT_SUCCESS: equ 0
SYS_READ: equ 3
SYS_WRITE: equ 4
SYS_EXIT: equ 1
NEW_LINE: equ 0ah
AsciiTable: db '................................ !"',"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;"
            db '<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
            db '{|}~...........................................................'
            db '...............................................................'
            db '.......'
align 4
Template: db '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '
DivPos:   db '| '
AsciiPart: db '................',NEW_LINE
TEMPLATELENGTH: equ $-Template
align 2
HexTable: db '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2'
          db '02122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f40'
          db '4142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606'
          db '162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f8081'
          db '82838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a'
          db '2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabacadaeafb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9babbbcbdbebfc0c1c2'
          db 'c3c4c5c6c7c8c9cacbcccdcecfd0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9dadbdcdddedfe0e1e2e'
          db '3e4e5e6e7e8e9eaebecedeeeff0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff'

section .bss
BUFFERSIZE: equ 16
Buffer: resb BUFFERSIZE

section .text

global _start ; make it visible

_start:
        mov ebx,STDIN
        lea ecx,[Buffer]
        mov edx,BUFFERSIZE
        mov esi,BUFFERSIZE

Fill:
        mov eax,SYS_READ
        int 80h                           ; call
        cmp eax,0                         ; check return value
        jl Err                            ; < 0 -> error
        jz Last                           ; 0 = EOF

        add ecx, eax                      ; Update where to load data
        sub edx, eax                      ; How many more bytes needed?
        jnz Fill                          ; Keep trying until we get 16 bytes

        ; At this point, we have read exactly 16 bytes.

        call OutputLine                   ; Turn esi bytes in Buffer into
                                          ; Template and print it

        jmp _start                        ; Get next line

; At this point, we have hit EOF.  Output any leftovers
; in the buffer.
Last:
        sub esi, edx                      ; How many did we really read?
        jz End                            ; Did we end on exactly 16 bytes?

        ; Blank out the Template and AsciiPart
        mov bx, 0x2020                    ; '  '
        mov edx,BUFFERSIZE

WriteBlanks:
        dec edx
        mov [Template+edx*2+edx],bx       ; write blank over Template
        mov [AsciiPart+edx],bl            ; write blank over AsciiPart
        jnz WriteBlanks

        call OutputLine                   ; Turn esi bytes in Buffer into
                                          ; Template and print it

; Exit the program
End:    mov ebx,EXIT_SUCCESS              ; EXIT_SUCCESS
Exit:   mov eax,SYS_EXIT
        int 80h

Err:    mov ebx,-1                        ; EXIT_FAILURE
        jmp Exit

; Input: esi: Number of chars to process from Buffer
; Clobbers: eax, ebx, edx, edx, esi
OutputLine:
        xor eax, eax
NextChar:                                 ; Process next char
        dec esi
        mov al,[Buffer+esi]               ; read byte from buffer
        mov bx,[HexTable+eax*2]           ; get corresponding symbols
        mov [Template+esi*2+esi],bx       ; write to template
        mov bl,[AsciiTable+eax]           ; get ASCII symbol
        mov [AsciiPart+esi],bl            ; write to template
        jnz NextChar                      ; ecx is an offset not a counter

        mov eax,SYS_WRITE
        mov ebx,STDOUT
        mov ecx,Template
        mov edx,TEMPLATELENGTH
        int 80h
        cmp eax,TEMPLATELENGTH
        jne Err

        ret
```

It *looks* right, but even if it is slightly flawed it should give you some ideas.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86 says `ESP` is a general-purpose register. `xor edx,edx` is a leftover from an early version that was using `edx` to index the table, it shouldn't be there. I tested your code and it appears to produce the same output.

Comment: The same article also says "Although the main registers [...] are 'general-purpose' [..] and can be used for anything, it was originally envisioned that they be used for".  In addition to 'programmer expectations,' other components can also expect that they be used in certain ways.  Ped7g mentions signals/interrupts, and there are also debuggers.  I don't have a linux link, but see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4ea06t0.aspx) page for Windows.